# Is it possible to join two tables of multiple rows by only the first ID in each table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have two tables of data:

```
Table A
ID    Colors
--    ------
1     Blue
1     Green
1     Red

Table B
ID    States
--    ------
1     MD
1     VA
1     WY
1     CA
```

Is it possible to join these tables so that I get the following instead of 12 rows?

```
ID    Colors    States
--    ------    ------
1     Blue      MD
1     Green     VA
1     Red       WY
1               CA
```

There's no association between the colors and states columns and the order of the columns doesn't matter. (e.g. Blue can be next to MD, VA, WY, or CA) The number of items in each column (Colors or States) per ID is not equal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `row_number()` to create a fake join column:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, a.colors, b.states
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.seqnum = a.seqnum
```

Actually, in Oracle, you can also just use `rownum`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, a.colors, b.states
from (select a.*, rownum as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.*, rownum as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.seqnum = a.seqnum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE (Common Table Expression) Like so:

```
WITH TableA (ID, Color) AS
(
    SELECT "ID", Color 
    FROM DatabaseName.TableA
)
, Joined AS (
    SELECT 
        a.ID AS "AID",
        a.Color
        b.ID AS "BID", 
        b."State"
    FROM, 
        TableA AS a
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN DatabaseName.TableB AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
)

SELECT
    AID,
    Color,
    State
FROM
    Joined
```

Comment: @@BRogers- dude, this will give error in Oracle: ;WITH... as well as this SELECT [ID]... Please stop confusing users or use proper syntax.

Comment: In Oracle... it's true you can't use the `;with`. Oracle also uses a double-quote instead of square brackets. Sorry about that, used to SQL more than Oracle... however, the rest works perfectly... instead of complaining about proper syntax and confusion.... why didn't you just comment the correct way? To me, that's a completely useless comment. Always look to improve something if you're going to post... not just complain. @Art thanks for bringing this up. But... be more useful in comments.

Comment: Oracle vs MS SQL discrepancy fixed in my answer.

Comment: @@BRogers - because the rest is irrelevant as this will not work and may confuse beginners or someone who is migrating from SQL SERVER to Oracle for example. And others would silently downvote you instead of communicating with you... I hope you understand my true intentions now.

Comment: @Art The rest of it works, and while it could confuse beginners or people transitioning... It's a valid answer. I'm grateful for you bringing that up! Truly, I am. If I was to bring up something like that I would also include the fix instead of just saying it doesn't work and not to confuse users. CTE's are pretty common and easier to use in the long run to understand queries (IMHO). The most common thing I see is temp tables, which I'm pretty strongly against.

Comment: @@BRogers-Do not take it so personally. All you had to do is to remove ; and []. That's it, this is all I asked - use proper syntax. And there is Gordon's example already (before your fixes) - no need improvements.